# AJAX call for Node/Express to render aPolymer iron-list

Tags: json, node.js, ajax, express, polymer

My goal: to render an `<iron-list>` by ajax call to Node.

Firstly, codes:

**index.handlebars**

```
<iron-ajax url="./allusers" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
<iron-list items="{{data}}" as="item">
   <template>
      <div>
         Name: {{item.name}}
      </div>
   </template>
</iron-list>
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/allusers', function(req, res){
  funct.getAllUsers()
    .then(function (allusers) {
      var data = [];
      allusers.forEach(function(eachuser) {
        data.push(JSON.stringify(eachuser));
      });
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      console.log("Error at getAllUsers: " + err);
    });
});
```

Here `getAllUsers()` is a mongodb function which returns an array by

```
collection.find().toArray()
```

And `allusers` should already be an array of JSON but with some formatting issue so I called `JSON.stringify` to make sure each element in the array is a properly formatted JSON object. But I still get this error:

> Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON

And my `<iron-list>` is always empty. Why?

## Update

The JSON data:

**allusers**

```
[{name: 'abc'},
 {name: 'bcd'}]
```

**data**

```
['{"name": "abc"}',
 '{"name": "bcd"}']
```

Comment: By the way, my polymer version is 1.2.4

Comment: can you post the json data?

Comment: @Santosh Thanks for asking. I posted it in the question body "Update" section. Now I see the issue may be the single quote in `data`. But how to adjust my code?

Comment: On each array item, parse the JSON.

Comment: @Santosh Parsing `data` will make it go back to the style of `allusers`. That throws the same error.

Comment: So I guess it all boils down to sanitizing the data... `And allusers should already be an array of JSON but with some formatting issue` can I know what kind of formatting issue are you facing ?

Comment: @Santosh I read a post saying Polymer only recognize json with double quotes in both key and value field. That is why I said that, I am not very sure though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143713/discussion-between-santosh-and-tic30).

Comment: "Polymer only recognize json with double quotes in both key and value field." - but that is only for passing strings to attributes - this does not apply to what you are doing here.

Your server application should return normal json application with proper `content-type` (maybe you are missing that), consider hinting the proper response type.

Comment: @Santosh, @Ergo Thank you all I resolved this issue by replacing the `iron-ajax` with jQuery ajax `$.getJSON()`. The JSON format in variable `allusers` is the normal json object format. Still not sure why `iron-ajax` is not working. If interested, we can discuss it further.